# New Login keychain created at each login

Tags: login, password, keyrings

Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit. Auto lagin is NOT disabled (i.e. I do have to enter my password to login). The password for the "Login" key chain (previously my *only* key chain is the same as my login password.

When I login, instead of unlocking the keyring with all my passwords on it, it creates a new "Login" keyring which is unlocked. I am then prompted for a password for my real "Login" keyring.

So I have a keyring called "Login" for every time I've logged in since this has started (sans the ones I've deleted), but only one (the one that was just created) actually gets unlocked at login.

[image: having just logged in and responded to the password prompt]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for a while. Here's how I finally fixed it.

First, open `seahorse` and create a new keyring, I called mine Extra, and copy anything you absolutely need to keep into that keyring.

Next, log out and drop to a VT (`Ctrl+Alt+F2`). Log in, and then `cd .local/share/keyrings/`. `ls` to see what keyring files are available, then `rm login* default` or otherwise remove all of the login keyrings, and the default file.

Log back in and everything should behave as normal except that you will need to re-authenticate all of your Online Accounts. If you use Google Chrome/Chromium next time it turns on it will sync all of its passwords back into the keyring as well.

---

tl;dr `rm .local/share/keyrings/{login*,default}` while not running GNOME/Unity.